# Error:(2,25) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Reference

Tags: kotlin

I have created an array, however, that array is highlighted in red and it won't compile. I have attached a screenshot and if anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Just to be a bit descriptive, I have checked other solutions here and I noticed that the problem was with a mismatch with Java bytecode and JVM target, well, these are set to Project bytecode version = 8 and JVM target = 1.8, as for the Kotlin, it is 1.3, I believe.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Attachment is not available.

Comment: Sorry. I just updated the question with the screenshot link embedded. I thought that went through. Please revisit the question and check for "screenshot". Thanks

Comment: Are these supposed to be Strings, but you forgot to put quotation marks around them?

Comment: No, they are not supposed to be Strings. It is an Array. I'm doing some practice on them after reading a book.

Comment: So they were supposed to be Strings. An Array of Strings.

Comment: Please include code as text rather than as image. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you use are Identifiers, and are not expressions like String Integer.

This representation shows you how to use String Values:

```
 fun main(){
    val brands = arrayOf("Samsung","Huawai","Nokia")
 }
```

This representation shows you how to use Integer Values:

```
   fun main(){
       val brands=arrayOf(52,48,24")
   }
```

For more info in kotlin use this link
[https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-data-type][1]

Comment: Thanks :-)  I see now see where I got it wrong. That worked. I won't forget this lesson again.